# "Error 81002 waiting for job" in TWS, can the allowed runtime be extended?

Tags: datastage, tivoli-work-scheduler

We have few Informatica & Datastage jobs which runs in TWS. When the job run time exceeds more than 3 hours TWS job use to fail with the below error..

```
Error: Error 81002 waiting for job
```

Is there any way to increase the time and make the TWS job not to fail and wait for the Datastage jobs to get completed?

Answer (score -2):

You could try setting the **DSE_SLAVE_CLOSE_SOCKET_ON_EXEC** environment variable:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/DSE_SLAVE_CLOSE_SOCKET_ON_EXEC.html

Comment: Can you edit the link text and explain what the variable is suppose to be set to and what it means? Without the latter information it appears to be just a link. [see "Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).